# Eslint replace, can't read method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I have this replace method to convert a url base64 to a Unit 8array but eslint can't read my replace method. 
I'm using vue so i can't turn off eslint on single line.

```
  function urlBase64ToUint8Array (base64String) {
    const padding = '='.repeat((4 - base64String.length % 4) % 4)
    const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')
    const rawData = window.atob(base64)
    const outputArray = new Uint8Array(rawData.length)

    for (let i = 0; i < rawData.length; ++i) {
      outputArray[i] = rawData.charCodeAt(i)
    }
    return outputArray
}
```

Here is my replace method. Is there a workaround to do the same thing or?

eslint gives me this error.

[image: eslint throw error]

Comment: What do you mean "eslint can't read my replace method"? Are you expecting eslint to issue a warning here (and it isn't), or is eslint issuing a warning when you don't expect it to? And you can [turn off eslint on a single line](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments).

Comment: Your code misses the identifier.

Comment: `const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')` this is the full code and eslint throws an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to escape `-` character. It's not special character here.

```
const base64 = (base64String + padding).replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')
```